# Unable to setup node in windows server 2012 R2

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, grid, webdriver, selenium-grid

**Selenium-hub:**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar -role hub
```

(**in my local machine**)

**Selenium-node:**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar -role node -hub http:/10.136.32.140:4444/grid/register
```

**(in virtual machine : windows server 2012 R2)**

Successfully setup done for hub (**in my local machine**) and I am trying to set up node in **virtual machine (windows server 2012 R2)** and I get below message. It doesn't work even with different ports but **it works if I change windows server to hub and local machine to node.** I don't know where is the mistake, I am unable to setup node in **VM** Kindly help !

```
15:17:29.452 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running on port 5555
15:17:29.452 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
15:17:29.468 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
15:17:29.468 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://10.136.32.140:4444/grid/register
15:17:50.530 INFO - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Connect to 10.136.32.140:4444 [/10.136.32.140] failed: Connection timed out: connect
15:18:16.561 INFO - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Connect to 10.136.32.140:4444 [/10.136.32.140] failed: Connection timed out: connect
15:18:42.561 INFO - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Connect to 10.136.32.140:4444 [/10.136.32.140] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: Update the question with the commands your have used to start the _Selenium Grid Hub_ and _Selenium Grid Node_

Comment: Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: Please update the main question with this information for a quicker analysis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium grid listening on node port instead of hub port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496191/selenium-grid-listening-on-node-port-instead-of-hub-port)

Comment: @DebanjanB, thanks for your reply. I checked the post you suggested but it looks I have different issue here i.e I can't register a node in VM (windows server 2012 R2). Kindly help !

Comment: Help us to analyze your issue by updating the question from your comment updates.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I updated my question with your suggestion,  is it OK
 now ?

Comment: Update the question with your _local machine_ IP address and _Selenium Grid Hub_ start up logs and the _Selenium Grid Hub_ logs generated when you try to register the node.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line
     java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar -role node -hub http:/10.136.32.140:4444/grid/register

To

```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.136.32.140:4444/grid/register -port:5555 (we can specify port number while configuring hub)
```

Comment: I tried with given info and below is the response: 
   `C:\Users\hameemo\Downloads>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar -role
node -hub http://10.136.32.140:4444/grid/register -port:5555
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed m
ain parameter '-port:5555' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class´

Comment: I tried by deleting ':' between port and 5555 but no success. Same error message : `14:28:06.125 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://10.136.32.140:4444/g
rid/register
14:28:27.203 INFO - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration
request: Connect to 10.136.32.140:4444 [/10.136.32.140] failed: Connection timed
 out: connect
14:28:53.243 INFO - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not respondi
ng: Connect to 10.136.32.140:4444 [/10.136.32.140] failed: Connection timed out:
 connect`