# What is wd/hub while creating an instance of AndroidDriver through Appium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium, selenium-grid

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:"+port+"/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Answer (score 1):

**wd** is the short form of *WebDriver*

**hub** refers to *Selenium Grid* configuration where the two components are:

- **Selenium Grid Hub** (is commonly termed as **hub**)
- **Selenium Grid Node** (is commonly termed as **node**)
- **wd/hub** is the part of the *uri* through which the **node** communicates with the **hub**

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [selenium grid listening on node port instead of hub port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496191/selenium-grid-listening-on-node-port-instead-of-hub-port)