# Not able to see selenium grid running when it is viewed from browser, when hub and node both are getting used from docker

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium4

Trying to see the grid console using following url:
http://SystemIP:4444/grid/console

[image: #]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This log message...

```
Creating a new remote node for http://172.18.0.3:5555
Added node xyz
Changing status of node xyz from DOWN to UP. Reason : http://172.18.0.3:5555 is ok
```

...implies that the *Remote Node* `http://172.18.0.3:5555` was successfully added and the status was changed from **DOWN** to **UP**.

From the image of the log messeges of the [Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647961/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-selenium-grid/59648301#59648301) I don't see any such issues.

So to view the grid console you need to access the url:

```
http://172.18.0.3:4444/grid/console
```

If the [Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496191/selenium-grid-listening-on-node-port-instead-of-hub-port/46524276#46524276) is hosted on the localhost you can also use either of the following urls:

- `http://localhost:4444/grid/console`
- `http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/console`